When $(x+1)^{m}$ is multiplied out, find the value of $m.$
When $(x+1)^{m}$ is multiplied out, we get the number of coefficients that are not divisible by $2,3$ and $5$ are  $64,16$ and $8$ respectively. Find the value of $m.$
I have an idea of trying Lucas theorem, but don't know how to apply this theorem for this problem. The problem may be hard, that's why I don't know where to start.
Any guidance will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Just to be clear, when we expand, we get $m+1$ terms and 64 of these terms have a coefficient that is not divisible by 2, 16 of these terms not divisible by 3 and 8 not divisible by 5. Is that correct? A nice question, with possibly multiple approaches.

If you use Lucas' theorem, try to find the first $m$ that satisfies the single condition that the number of coefficients not divisible by $2$ is $64$.  Then try to find the second $m$, and see if you can detect a pattern.  Ignore the divisibility by $3$ and $5$ for the time being.

What's the source of this problem?

@SarveshRavichandranIyer , the problem is proposed by me.

The relevant consequence of Lucas's theorem is that the number of binomial coefficients $\binom mk,0\le k\le m$ not divisible by $p$ is
$$\prod_{d\in\text{base-}p\text{ expansion of }m}(d+1)$$
A little thought shows that our desired $m$ must thus have

in base $2$, exactly six $1$s
in base $3$, exactly four $1$s and zero $2$s
in base $5$, either exactly three $1$s or one $3$ and one $1$, and all the rest $0$s

The base-$3$ condition implies $m$ is even and that the three-$1$s case of the base-$5$ condition cannot be true.
Visual inspection of the output of a small Python program that checks numbers satisfying the base-$5$ condition against the other two conditions shows that
$$m=1000=1111101000_2=1101001_3=13000_5$$
works (verification).

Lucas's theorem is a good idea.
For any prime $p$, we aim to count the number of $k$ such that $\binom{m}{k} \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$.  One simple observation is that, if $0 \leq k_0 \leq m_0 < p$, then $\binom{m_0}{k_0} \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$.
Towards Lucas's theorem, we write $$m = m_np^n+\ldots+m_0p^0 \\ k = k_np^n + \ldots + k_0p^0$$
where each $m_i, k_i$ is between $0$ and $p-1$, inclusive.  Then Lucas's theorem says $$\binom{m}{k} \equiv \prod_{i=0}^n\binom{m_i}{k_i} \pmod p.$$ This will be nonzero if and only if $\binom{m_i}{k_i} \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$ for each $i$, which by the above observation means $0 \leq k_i \leq m_i$ for each $i$.  Therefore, the number of $k$s such that $\binom{m}{k} \not\equiv 0\pmod p$ is given by $$\prod_{i=0}^n(m_i+1)$$

In your case, this means $m$ satisfies
$$64 = 2^{\text{# of 1s appearing in the binary representation of } m}\\ 16 = 2^{\text{# of 1s appearing in the base 3 representation of } m} \times 3^{\text{# of 2s appearing in the base 3 representation of } m} \\ 8 = \prod_{i=1}^4 (i+1)^{\text{# of '} i \text{'s appearing in the base 5 representation of } m}$$
or there are six $1$s appearing in base 2, four $1$s appearing in base 3, no $2$s appearing in base 3, and no $2$s or $4$s appearing in base 5. Further, if $i$ $1$s appear in base 5 and $j$ $3$s appear in base 5, then $(i,j)$ is either $(3,0)$ or $(1,1)$.

I'll be honest here.  I know of no way to find $m$ except by brute force at this point.  I might get to it later if I think of a method, but otherwise I'll leave it here.
